# How can I add custom bullets to tinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce, tinymce-4

I want to add a few extra option to the bullets dropdown on tinyMCE, is that possible?

I want to add ► type of bullet and different color options. (red, blue, etc...)

Comment: You can add bullets to a specific class with `:before` on whatever element you want

Comment: @ntgCleaner you should expand on your answer. Perhaps offer a small example or a more clear reference to the API/docs

Comment: @ntgCleaner For example, if you were referring to CSS selectors, it might help to be explicit about it. An example might look like this: `p::before { 
    content: "► ";
}`

Comment: Thanks @Andres, but this was answered a year and a half ago. Before I could expand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. In your tinyMCE config, you need to specify:

```
style_formats: [
    {
         title: 'Custom Bullet',
             selector: 'ul', 
             classes: 'custom1'
         }
],
```

From there, you need to specify the styling in the CSS:

```
.custom1 { list-style-image: url('custom1.png'); }
```

See this for more info: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-formatting/#style_formats

Comment: I go that working... thanks... But it won't change in the editor, I have to save the content and it will display. Is it possible to do so after I select the style it would display on the editor screen?

Comment: TinyMCECustomConfig("custom2","style_formats", "{title: 'Custom Bullet', selector: 'ul', classes: 'custom1'}");